# Calling a protected function from instance inside a derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

Currently, I am trying to solve the following situation.

I have a `classB` which contains some objects from a `classA`. Each `classA` has a function `foo` which needs to be executed. In the context of the program it makes since that `classB`inherits from `classA` since will need all of its functionality.

I would like to call the protected function from an instance of a base class.

I have the following test code:

```
#include <iostream>

class baseA 
{
    protected:
    virtual bool foo()
    {
        std::cout <<"Base foo in action" << std::endl;
        return true;
    }
};

class classB
:public baseA
{
    public:
    baseA obj1_;

    virtual bool foo()
    {
        std::cout <<"I am going to call base foo" << std::endl;
        bool a = obj1_.foo(); // Can't be called
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    classB obj; 
    obj.foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Currently is does not work because the function `foo`is protected in the current context.

I get the following error:  `error: ‘virtual bool baseA::foo()’ is protected within this contex`

Is there a way to make it work while maintaining the protected specifier?

Best regards

Comment: You need to explain in more detail what you're trying to accomplish. Otherwise, I don't see how anyone could propose a solution. There's no way for you to simply "override" the fact that it's protected (well, there are certain techniques, but they shouldn't be used... http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/076.htm)

Comment: What is "it does not work"? Any compiler error?

Comment: I question why you have `baseA obj1_;` in the first place. In derivedA::foo() you can call `baseA::foo()` just by writing `baseA::foo();` Here: [https://ideone.com/hkjfuW](https://ideone.com/hkjfuW)

Comment: @273K. The compiler gives the error: ` error: ‘virtual bool baseA::foo()’ is protected within this context`. I will give more context to the question

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a way. You can put a protected "forwarding" function into the base.

```
struct Base {
protected:
  virtual void theFunc() = 0;
  
  static void callTheFuncOn(Base *b) {
    b->theFunc();
  }
};

struct Derived: Base {
  void test(Base *b) {
    callTheFuncOn(b);
  }
};
```